How would I display this data to the user?
I just started learning 4 weeks ago and I am trying to use HttpGet to retrieve information based on the current logged in user and display the information in a list. I am using WASM.
The code section of my razor page
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await companyService.GetAsync(userCompanies);
}

My GetAsync method in the CompanyService.cs
public async Task<List<CompanyDTO>> GetAsync(CompanyDTO company, string currentProId)
{
    var client = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync($"{AuthUrl}/retrieve-companies?currentProId={currentProId}");

    if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Enhanced error handling - consider returning an empty list
        return new List<CompanyDTO>();
    }

    return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<CompanyDTO>>() ?? new List<CompanyDTO>();
}

The Controller
`[HttpGet("retrieve-companies")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CompanyDTO>>> GetAsync(CompanyDTO company)
{
    var currentProId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var companies = await companyInterface.GetAsync(null!, currentProId!);

    return Ok(company);
}`

My repository
public async Task<List<CompanyDTO>> GetAsync(CompanyDTO company, string currentProId)
{
    // Ensure a valid currentProId
    if (!int.TryParse(currentProId, out int proId))
    {
        // Maybe return an empty list or a suitable error response
        return new List<CompanyDTO>();
    }

    var companies = await appDbContext.Companies
                .Where(c => c.ProId == proId)
                .Include(c => c.Pro)
                .ToListAsync();

    var companyDTOs = companies.Select(c => new CompanyDTO
    {
        Name = c.Name,
    }).ToList();
    return companyDTOs;
}

I've tried rearranging my code and checking variables, honestly I am still learning the flow so I couldn't tell you if what I have tried made a difference or not. But what I can say is that my endpoint does retrieve the DTO's data according to swagger.
